# JavaScript ECMA-262 re-write eval function

Tags: javascript

I am using a software tool (Opus Pro-Digital Workshop-UK) that uses OpusScript (a type of ECMA-262 JS). I've created an eval function, unsure how else to create the result. It works OK, but there are many online mentions of problems using eval functions. So, I am posting the function and hoping to get help re-writing it without eval, if this is possible:

```
//len = 36 //puzzle pieces-F1-F36
    function combiner10(len){
    s200 = new Array(214,401,607,791,977,1132,1140,1141,1142,1143,1146,1057,916,760,611,465,312,175,75,77,77,77,77,65,186,364,631,837,1035,1067,218,219,223,220,1158,1152);
    s300 = new Array(56,58,63,67,66,69,208,320,463,565,647,704,704,704,702,701,699,701,703,581,457,328,202,74,694,700,698,696,701,697,566,448,335,201,533,374);
    for (var i=1;i<=len;i++)
          eval("F"+i+".SetPosition(s200[i-1],s300[i-1])");
    }
```

I am a novice at scripting.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Replace that with an array.

Comment: What is `F1`…`F36`? Why not use an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a reason why you need to use `eval()` here at all.

Put your pieces into an array so instead of variables named F1-F36, you simply use an array that contains each piece.  Then you can do this:

```
var pieces = [puzzle pieces F1-F36 in this array];   // F1 in the 0 position

function combiner10(len){
    var s200 = [214,401,607,791,977,1132,1140,1141,1142,1143,1146,1057,916,760,611,465,312,175,75,77,77,77,77,65,186,364,631,837,1035,1067,218,219,223,220,1158,1152];
    var s300 = [56,58,63,67,66,69,208,320,463,565,647,704,704,704,702,701,699,701,703,581,457,328,202,74,694,700,698,696,701,697,566,448,335,201,533,374];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          pieces[i].SetPosition(s200[i],s300[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, local variables should be declared with `var` in front of them.

Comment: Made minor Opus syntax changes. Thank you, this worked.